# C# xml serialization - multiple choices for a property

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I've got a variable failure, that can have three values: passed, failure, or error.  What I want to happen during serialization is to create an element based on the value. For passed, I want to ignore the element.  For failure I want a failure element.  For error, I want an error element.  How can this be done?

In the class Test, there is a list of Steps called m_steps.  In Step there is a variable called m_failure, which holds passed, failure or error.  I want the element created by m_steps to be non-element(passed), failure, or error.

```
[XmlRoot("testsuite")]
public class Suite
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string m_name;

    [XmlElement("testcase")]
    public List<Test> m_tests;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string m_timestamp;


public class Test
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string m_name;

    [XmlElement("failure")] // want to be ignore, failure or error instead of just failure
    public List<Step> m_steps;

    [XmlAttribute("assertions")]
    public int m_assertions;
}


public class Step
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string m_failure; // holds passed, failure, or error

    [XmlTextAttribute]
    public string m_message;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string m_image;

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string m_type;
}
```

Looking for:

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<testsuite name=" SimpleCalculationsSuite" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  -<testcase name="Add 3+4" assertions="1"></testcase>
  -<testcase name="Fail 3-4" assertions="1"> 
     <failure type="Text">The control text is not correct. Expected-7 Actual--1</failure> 
   </testcase> 
  -<testcase name="Error 3*4" assertions="1"> 
     <error type="Click">The * button was not found</error> 
 </testsuite>
```

From:

```
Suite: SimpleCalculationsSuite
Test:Add 3+4
Passed:Text:The control text, 7, is correct.
Test:Fail 3-4
Failed:Text:The control text is not correct. Expected-7 Actual--1
Test:Error 3*4
Error:Click: The * button was not found
```

Comment: It seems to me that an Enum would be a better approach, no?

Comment: Do you mean you want a variable of type Failure or a variable of type Error?

Comment: Just a quick point on your code - you're using "m_" for public members.  "m_" is typically used for private and sometimes protected members.

Comment: I wasn't too worried about it.  The variables should be private.  But I'm just running this through the command line to convert a text file to xml.  I never access the variables, just set them through a constructor.

Comment: Can you provide a mock up/sample xml output that you are going for.  Im not entirely certain I can see the same picture as you, because it looks to me like renaming it Steps, or Results, would be the easiest way, and telling people to look, or looking yourself, at the m_failure field for the actual step.

Comment: Error and Failure would come from the same property m_steps.  Currently I can only do one or the other.

Comment: Each Test could have multiple Steps. What if there are some Steps with "passed", some with "failure" and some with "error"? I don't think you're going to have much luck with this without custom serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying Test to also include a list of errors.  With this I was able to have both failure and error nodes present in the XML file.  I also had to modify some of the program to allow this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx

Comment: Ugh.  I tried a manual implementation of that once.  Its a beast, and never the way I would recommend going.  It would work though.  Knowing me, I was probably both doing it wrong and over engineering the thing, but it was still a beast.

Answer (score 0):

I will not use the same classes from your example, I'll give a little example of myself.

You need to implement the method public bool ShouldSerialize**Name**()  where Name is the name of the attribute of which you want to have the control of the serialization.

For example, I have this class:

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializeExample
{
    public string ResultType { get; set; }

    public string Error { get; set; }

    public string Failure { get; set; }

    public List<string> Steps { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeError()
    {
        return "Error".Equals(ResultType);
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeFailure()
    {
        return "Failure".Equals(ResultType);
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeSteps()
    {
        return ShouldSerializeError() || ShouldSerializeFailure();
    }
}
```

If I have this class instance:

```
SerializeExample ex1 = new SerializeExample { ResultType = "Success" };
```

Then, only this XML is serialized:

```
<SerializeExample>
  <ResultType>Success</ResultType>
</SerializeExample>
```

If I create this other class and serialize it:

```
SerializeExample ex2 = new SerializeExample { ResultType = "Error", Error = "Invalid data from user", Steps = new List<string>() };
```

Then, this XML is generated.

```
<SerializeExample>
  <ResultType>Error</ResultType>
  <Error>Invalid data from user</Error>
  <Steps />
</SerializeExample>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I need.  I'm having issues because I have two classes.  The decision on whether or not to create the node failure or error is based on a decision that needs to be made on a property outside of the Test class, Step.failure.

Comment: @TIMBERings Oh man, true! then put 3 different elements,  [XmlElement("failure")][XmlElement("error")]and [XmlElement("ignore")] and the user ShouldSerializeWhatever() ... based on whether the collection is empty or has values. This trick will actually work.  Otherwise, welcome to the nice task of implementing ISerializable